# How to select next non-null value In each column. T-SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I am trying to select the last non-null value per column based on a date value.

I have a table that looks like this -

```
Email           Name1   Name2   Job     Date
Test1@test.com  Ron     NULL    NULL    2015-01-01 00:00:00.000
Test1@test.com  Dave    Smith   NULL    2014-01-01 00:00:00.000
Test1@test.com  NULL    NULL    NULL    2013-01-01 00:00:00.000
Test2@test.com  NULL    Smith   NULL    2014-01-01 00:00:00.000
Test2@test.com  NULL    Ford    Plumber 2015-01-01 00:00:00.000`
```

I want to display the newest non-null value for each column per email address.

The output should be -

```
Email           Name1   Name2   Job
Test1@test.com  Ron     Smith   NULL
Test2@test.com  NULL    Ford    Plumber
```

I have already written some pretty ugly SQL to solve this problem however I want to apply this logic to another table with a lot more columns.

My Question is - Is there an easier way to do this without having to join for each column?

Current solution is as follows -

```
select distinct  a.[Email],b.[Name1],c.[Name2],d.[job] from 
(
select [Email] from #test
)
A
left join 
(
SELECT [Email],
 FIRST_VALUE([Name1]) over(partition by [Email] order by [Date] desc) as [Name1]
from #test
where [Name1] is not null
) b
on a.[Email] = b.[Email]
left join 
(
SELECT [Email],
FIRST_VALUE([Name2]) over(partition by [Email] order by [Date] desc) as [Name2]
from  #test
where [Name2] is not null
) c
on a.[Email] = c.[Email]
left join 
(
select [Email],
FIRST_VALUE([Job]) over(partition by [Email] order by [Date] desc) as [Job]
from #test
where  [Job] is not null
) d
on a.[Email] = d.[Email]
```

Here's the DDL/DML for the example table if this helps -

```
create table #test
([Email] nvarchar(50),
[Name1]  nvarchar(50),
[Name2] nvarchar(50),
[Job] nvarchar(50),
[Date] datetime)

insert into #test
values
('Test1@test.com', 'Ron', null,null,'20150101'),
('Test1@test.com', 'Dave' ,'Smith',null, '20140101'),
('Test1@test.com', null, null, null ,'20130101'),
('Test2@test.com', null, 'Smith', null, '20140101'),
('Test2@test.com', null, 'Ford', 'Plumber','20150101')
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are ways that don't require so many joins.  None are simple because SQL Server doesn't support the `ignore nulls` option on `lag()`.

Basically, you'll need to do logic on each column.  One method without a subquery is:

```
select distinct email,
       first_value(name1) over (partition by email
                                order by (case when name1 is not null then date else '2000-01-01' end) desc
                               ) as name1,
       . . .
from #test;
```

An alternative uses outer apply:

```
select t.email, name1, . . .
from (select distinct email from #test t) t outer apply
     (select top 1 name1
      from #test t2
      where t2.email = t.email and name1 is not null
      order by date desc
     ) name1 . . .
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `FIRST_VALUE` with `DISTINCT`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT Email, 
       FIRST_VALUE(Name1) OVER (PARTITION BY Email 
                                ORDER BY CASE 
                                           WHEN Name1 IS NULL THEN '19000101' 
                                           ELSE [Date] 
                                         END DESC) AS Name1,
       FIRST_VALUE(Name2) OVER (PARTITION BY Email 
                                ORDER BY CASE 
                                           WHEN Name2 IS NULL THEN '19000101' 
                                           ELSE [Date] 
                                         END DESC) AS Name2,
       FIRST_VALUE(Job) OVER (PARTITION BY Email 
                                ORDER BY CASE 
                                           WHEN Job IS NULL THEN '19000101' 
                                           ELSE [Date] 
                                         END DESC) AS Job
FROM test
```